# Google Optimize + AMP

Tags: amp-html, google-optimize

How do I integregate Google Optimize with AMP? I've tried adding the gtag code using the custom element amp-analytics but testing diagnostics in Google Optimize says that the plugin/analytics cannot be found. My code works great if I use the regular gtag.js but then it isn't AMP validated. Please advise.

How do I get the optimize code working with amp?

https://developers.google.com/optimize/devguides/amp-experiments